# Firestore TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For some reason I am getting the above error.
Using  "node": "10", "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",  "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"

Any thoughts why the top-level of the database, into which I need to write this collection, is being seen as a null?

```
  functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}/{subCol}/{docId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    let newDoc = change.after.exists ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(change.after.data())) : null;
       return newDoc == null
      ? null
      : change.after.ref.parent.parent.parent.parent
          .collection(context.params.subCol)
          .doc(context.params.docId)
          .set(newDoc);
  });
```

Comment: Could you please share how are you initializing Firestore? Should be sth like this: `const functions = require('firebase-functions')`, Also make sure that the document exists. What happen if you hard code `users/{userId}/{subCol}/{docId}`? [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing-triggered_functions) are some examples about it.

Comment: of course, const functions = require("firebase-functions");
the doc does exist, otherwise the function wouldn't be triggered so no null would be thrown. instead of the relative parents, as a workaround, i'm now using just the root db, which works so the issue is not about hardcoding. I've no idea why the parents are not giving the same result.

Comment: Nice you make it work, I see you have 4 levles of `.parent.parent.parent.parent`, but it should be only 3?